# How to know when an Activity dies in a Fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment that is being loaded by an `Activity`.

I know things such as

```
onPause()

onStop()
```

On stop gets called too late and sometimes not at all.

But my Activity dies I want to know so that I can tell my fragment to clean up.

What is the fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not realyl sure what your question is, but perhaps you will find this useful.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

I suggest reading up on the fragment life-cycle [image]

Comment: It seems that onDetach() tells me what I need. Thx.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to mark this as the correct answer for future people

Answer (score 0):

`onDestroy()` will be called just before the `Fragment` is destroyed. This could happen because the parent `Activity` is also destroyed or because the `Fragment` is no longer displayed.